# Print graph into terminal. Perl

Tags: perl, graph, module

I just found the GD::Graph module, but it prints graph into file.

I want to create a kind of a monitor which prints on to terminal.

**For example how could i print a graph (not exactly, but similar so it fits to terminal) like this onto a terminal?**

**Updated**

```
use strict;
use GD::Graph::bars;
use GD::Graph::hbars;
use GD::Graph::Data;
require 'save.pl';

my $data = GD::Graph::Data->new([
    ["1st","2nd","3rd","4th","5th","6th","7th", "8th", "9th"],
    [    1,    2,    5,    6,    3,  1.5,    1,     3,     4],
]) or die GD::Graph::Data->error;

my @names = qw/sample11 sample11-h/;

for my $my_graph (GD::Graph::bars->new, GD::Graph::hbars->new)
{
    my $name = shift @names;

    print STDERR "Processing $name\n";

    $my_graph->set(
        x_label         => 'X Label',
        y_label         => 'Y label',
        title           => 'A Simple Bar Chart',
        #y_max_value     => 8,
        #y_tick_number   => 8,
        #y_label_skip    => 2,

        #x_labels_vertical => 1,

        # shadows
        bar_spacing     => 8,
        shadow_depth    => 4,
        shadowclr       => 'dred',

        transparent     => 0,
    )
    or warn $my_graph->error;

    $my_graph->plot($data) or die $my_graph->error;
    save_chart($my_graph, $name);
}
```

Comment: `print IMG $graph->plot..` => `print $graph->plot..`

Comment: @mpapec, thx but i didn't get it, can u please tell me on example?

Comment: check what `sub save_chart{}` says.

Comment: Find an ASCII Art chart/graph module instead of a graphical one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's simple enough to print the graph to STDOUT. Instead of calling `save_chart()`, you'd just do something like:

```
print $my_graph->png;
```

But it's very unlikely that your monitor can understand raw PNG data being thrown at it. You'll want to write the plot to an image file and display the file in some way.

But it's hard to be more helpful without knowing more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, i just want to print simple graph with no fancy stuff, which should be fine on STDOUT.
In future i just want to make monitor of proc stat from it.

Comment: How do you propose to display the image on your monitor without some kind of image display software? Are you looking for [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art)?

Comment: @DaveCross Yes I am looking ASCII Art. on console The Y(X) values will be in an array and X is the number of iterations which is simply indices of the array. I want to use special character say "*".

Answer (score 2):

You could try hbar and modify it to suit your needs:

https://github.com/xxfelixxx/perl-term-colormap/blob/master/bin/hbar

```
  echo '
     1  one
     1  one
     2  two
     5  five
     8  eight
     13 thirteen
     21 twenty one
  ' | hbar
```

[image: hbar e]

Comment: How can I display a vertical Bar Graph? My Y(X) values are in an array and X is the number of iterations of algorithm, the indices of the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do what you need with Graph::Easy ?

```
Graph::Easy - Convert or render graphs (as ASCII, HTML, SVG or via
Graphviz)
```